# Is there a name for this pattern that uses anonymous classes in Java?

Tags: design-patterns

The pattern in question involves an abstract class that has a method which does some work, and then calls an abstract method. The class is used by subclassing it in an anonymous class, and specifying the behaviour of the abstract method. An example:

```
/* The abstract class */
abstract class WebCall {
    String url;

    WebCall(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    void call() {
        // Make call to url
        // Callback
        if (worked) {
            success();
        } else {
            failure();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void success();

    protected abstract void failure();

}
```

and the you would use the class like so:

```
new WebCall(someUrl) {
    @Override
    protected void success() {
        // Implementation
    }

    @Override
    protected void failure() {
        // Implementation
    }
}.call();
```

A real world example is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) from Android. Does this pattern have a common name?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question?

Comment: Nope. I used it with AsycTask for an Android project a while back, and used the pattern to refactor a messy async webcall yesterday, which got me wondering if it had a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and isn't particularly related to the use of anonymous classes - that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Ah OK. I understood that anonymous classes weren't mandatory, but that's the only way I'd seen it used.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern. You provide a skeletal implementation in abstract class and define abstract methods in subclasses. This pattern is from GoF book.